# Unable to display images in my view with local IIS Web Server. It works with IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

I work on an ASP.NET MVC3 solution with Visual Studio 2010. I have a view displaying images obtained from a WCF service call. This view did not render correctly through local IIS Web Server. Then I try with local IIS Express and I realised that everything works as expected. So I concluded something is wrong wi my IIS Web erver configuration. I would like to be able to work with IIS Web Server.

Here is an extract of the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<img src="@Url.Action("DownloadImage", new { imageID = 72 })" />
<img src="@Url.Action("DownloadImage", new { imageID = 73 })" />
...
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing complicated here. The interesting part in only the image tags. I call an action in my controller who call a WCF service to render the images (from my database).

When I configure my solution to work with IIS Express, it works pretty well:

[image]

You see on the screenshot below that my images are correctly obtained.

[image]

When I configure my colution to work with IIS Web Server, it doesn't work anymore:

[image]

You see on the screenshot below that my images are never obtained.

[image]

I spent a lot of time on this problem. I really would like to be able to work with my local IIS Web Server.

Don't hesitate to ask me config, code or anything else to help you understand what's going wrong here.

Thanks.

EDIT

As Darin talked about session state, below is the IIS Web Server configuration for Session State.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it looks like the requests for the images are returning HTTP Status 200, which means the server responded "Ok, here's your image".  So have you looked at the HTML that's being generate to make sure there's nothing funky there?

Comment: What happens when you type `http://localhost/WebUI/project/DownloadImage/72` in your browser address bar? Do you see the image? Is the controller action hit? Is the web service called? And what about when you force cache refresh `Ctrl+F5`?

Comment: When I type `http://localhost/WebUI/project/DownloadImage/72´ directly in my address bar I see the image. No problem. The controller action is hit and the web service is called. Ctrl+F5 still OK for displaying the image. I think I got problems when I have several calls at the same time. This problem reminds me another one where I had multiple ajax calls at the same time (for MVC RemoteValidation on multiple fields) then I noticed the same problem: calls waiting and never ending like here.

Comment: That's weird indeed. Are you using ASP.NET Session? Because if you do you cannot send concurrent requests from the same session. They will be executed sequentially. Could you try this in a real web browser? Like Google Chrome, FireFox or Safari. From your screenshot I can see that you are currently using IE which personally I can hardly consider as a web browser.

Comment: Am I using ASP.NET Session? In fact, this is my collegua who do all the plumbing in this asp.net mvc project (I'm not very familiar with all about asp.net). I do a search in the entire solution for the word 'session' and found some `using System.Web.SessionState;` (unused) references. I removed all, compile and retry and nothing changed. I also try with Google Chrome and I got the same result.

Comment: @Darin I inspect the IIS Web Server configuration about session state. Maybe this is important to show you. See my updated question (at the bottom).

Comment: I was asking if you are using ASP.NET session in your code, not how your web.config looks like.

Comment: No, I don't use ASP.NET session in my code.